# Decouple validity of two radio inputs with same name

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have a form with two `<input>`s with the same name. When one of them is required and unselected (thus, invalid), the other one is also characterized as invalid:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <form id="form">
    <input id="rad1" type="radio" name="my radio 3" value="option 1" required>
    <input id="rad2" type="radio" name="my radio 3" value="option 2">
  </form>

  <script>
    function checkValid() {
      console.log('Should be valid form: ' + document.getElementById('form').checkValidity());
      console.log('Rad1 should show false:  ' + document.getElementById('rad1').checkValidity());
      console.log('Rad2 should show true:  ' + document.getElementById('rad2').checkValidity());
    }

    checkValid();
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I would expect the second radio input to be valid. How can I make `#rad2` valid (i.e. `checkValidity()` return `true`)? Why is the validity coupled between these two radios?

I read every possible MDN doc about this but I can't find an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set a radio button group as required, the requirement is that an option is selected.  If you want to verify that a specific option is checked, you will need to use something like `var selected = document.querySelectorAll('#Rad1:checked');var isSelected = selected.length > 0 ? true: false;`

Notice how as you check the radios in my adjusted snip below, they both change to TRUE:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <form id="form">
    <input id="rad1" type="radio" name="my radio 3" value="option 1" required>
    <input id="rad2" type="radio" name="my radio 3" value="option 2">
  </form>

  <script>
    function checkValid() {
      console.log('Should be valid form: ' + document.getElementById('form').checkValidity());
      console.log('Rad1 should show false:  ' + document.getElementById('rad1').checkValidity());
      console.log('Rad2 should show true:  ' + document.getElementById('rad2').checkValidity());
    }

    checkValid();
    $('[name="my radio 3"]').on('change', function() {
      checkValid();
    })
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```